# How to remove 3px left & right extra space on buttons in Safari 5?

Tags: css, button, safari, webkit

I am trying to style buttons in my current project cross browser. When I checked those buttons in Safari, they looked different than in any other browser, even Chrome. In general buttons looks the same in FF, IE6-8, Opera and Chrome. But in Safari buttons have 3px of unknown extra space on left and right sides, so buttons looks wider in Safari rather than in Chrome or other browser. Total width of button in Safari web inspector 6px larger than in Chrome web inspector. Also, this strange behavior occurs only if button have width:auto, with fixed width buttons appears just fine.  Since Safari and Chrome have same layout engine (webkit), I`m in a little embarrassment.

Here is the demo of what I`m talking about:

http://iliadraznin.com/examples/css-only-buttons/ - check blue buttons in Chrome and then compare with Safari (you can see exact difference in web inspector).

Upd.: This example is not mine, it is just illustrates how Safari behaves. Here is my exact CSS and HTML:

```
<button class="blueButton" type="submit">Register</button>

.blueButton {
    color:#fff;
    background:#007ec6;
    border:2px solid #211b4d;
    cursor:pointer;
font:14px Arial;
text-shadow:#003585 0 -1px 1px;
width:auto;
overflow: visible;
padding:0 13px;
height:26px;
white-space:nowrap;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px;
behavior:url(PIE.htc);
position:relative;}

button::-moz-focus-inner {padding:0;border:0;}
```

If you will remove padding completely you will see exactly that extra little space in Safari

Is there any way to get rid of this extra button space in Safari?

Comment: As I look at this, you might help yourself and us by paring down your example further. Only one button. The `b.gradient` is irrelevant. Remove HTML and CSS that don't serve to showcase this problem exactly.

Comment: This example actually is not mine, it is just illustrates how Safari behaves. I`ve updated question and added exact CSS and HTML from my real project

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer you seek:

```
.blueButton {
    color:#fff;
    background:#007ec6;
    border:2px solid #211b4d;
    cursor:pointer;
    font:14px Arial;
    text-shadow:#003585 0 -1px 1px;
    width:auto;
    overflow: visible;
    padding:0 13px;
    height:26px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    behavior:url(PIE.htc);
    position:relative;
}

.blueButton::-moz-focus-inner {padding:0;border:0;} 
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .blueButton {
        margin: 0px;
    }
}
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer - the -moz-focus-inner and -webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio strip that extra space out perfectly.